# Is it possible to take advantage of case class inheritance in pattern matching in Scala 2.10.0?

Tags: scala

I could not find an answer to this simple question, maybe I used the wrong keywords to search.

To create an AST I need nodes such as Number, Add, Sub, Mul, Div and so forth.
Since many math operations share the same structure, how can I treat them all under the same pattern matching case? E.g. the lines below are said to be not syntactically correct:

```
object AST {
  sealed abstract class Expr
  case class MathOp(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Number extends Expr

  case class Add(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends MathOp(e1, e2)
  case class Sub(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends MathOp(e1, e2)
}
```

The intention is to be able to do:

```
expr match {
  case MathOp(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) => //do something that would be done to Add, Sub, Mul, Div
  case Number => //do another thing
}
```

Comment: Case classes and inheritance are like oil and soap; they don't mix well.  Combine them at your own risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

case classes do much more than adding pattern matching extractors, e.g. they add equality, product iterator and arity, etc., and so [odd things](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3289) happen under inheritance. Therefore, case class inheritance was deprecated before and is now impossible in Scala 2.10.

For your case, you want a custom extractor (`unapply` method):

```
object AST {
  sealed trait Expr
  object MathOp {
    def unapply(m: MathOp): Option[(Expr, Expr)] = Some(m.e1 -> m.e2)
  }
  sealed trait MathOp extends Expr {
    def e1: Expr
    def e2: Expr
  }
  case class Number extends Expr

  case class Add(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends MathOp
  case class Sub(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends MathOp
}
```

---

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333445/replacing-case-class-inheritance-with-extractors-preserving-exhaustiveness-check)

Comment: I have seen this workaround before (it is probably the official one), but IMO when one uses case classes, at least to pattern matching, one is looking for simplicity. But ok, I can delimit an untouchable area inside the AST object to keep the `traits` and `unapplies` or find some way to encapsulate/'implicitate' them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand the problem, I have no reason to use "case classes" for the children. Hopefully the correct code is as follows:

```
object AST {
  sealed abstract class Expr
  case class MathOp(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Number extends Expr

  class Add(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends MathOp(e1, e2)
  class Sub(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends MathOp(e1, e2)
}

expr match {
  case MathOp(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) => //do something that would be done to Add, Sub, Mul, Div
  case Number => //do another thing
}
```

Comment: Actually, I will need to pattern match the sub cases later... Any help?

Comment: Back to the `case classes` and `override val` the args.

Comment: Case-to-case inheritance is prohibited. Great... What is a non-leaf extractor?